# laravel model fetch data with custom value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have problem with laravel. I crate model whose name Zlecenia and need to fetch data with custom variable. I need to add a url value to this model.

My controller

```
$zlecenia = new Zlecenia();
$q = $zlecenia->with('users')->withLinks()
    ->orderBy('zlecenia.id', 'desc')
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->where('end',0)
    ->where('kategorie', '>', 0)
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

my model

```
public function withLinks($id,$slug){
    return route('ZleceniaZlecenie',['id'=>$id,'slug'=>$slug]);
}
```

How I can get data whose after fetch view like this:

```
{
"id": 21,
"created_at": "2017-08-01 08:51:08",
"updated_at": "2017-08-01 08:51:08",
"name": "fasd asdf",
"active": 1,
"user_id": 3,
"description": "asd fasdf",
"winner_id": null,
"end": 0,
"kategorie": 4,
"link": "slugValue",
"users": {
"id": 3,
"name": "test",
"email": "kontakt@teamwant.pl",
},
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/3/slugValue"
},
```

If you can see I add a "url" value and this value I need to generate it from function withLinks().

slug in withLinks == link value from model/db

id in withLinks == id value from model/db

Comment: You do not need that right in your model attributes, make a method (lets say `getSlug()` that if you call will generate the slug (url) for you. If you persist you can hack around and add the attribute itself using I think [accesors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) but I advise you to not. And please code in ENGLISH, you help yourself and your successors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all making active record queries in controller is a bad practice, if I understood question right you need to path two models (array of model) in your view, first:

```
public static function getSomeModel() {

return self::with('users')
    ->orderBy('zlecenia.id', 'desc')
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->where('end',0)
    ->where('kategorie', '>', 0)->take(5)->get();

}
```

second - url

Controller can looks like this:

```
public function getSomeRoute() {

$input = Input::all();

isset($input["id"]) $id = $input["id"];
isset($input["slug"]) $slug = $input["slug"];

$models = ["SomeModel" => SomeModel::getSomeModel(), "url" => "http://example.com/".$id."/".$slug];

return view("view", ["models" => $models]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select` function to create value holder on the fly. 
I am from Codeigniter background but you can get the general idea.

```
$zlecenia = new Zlecenia();
$q = $zlecenia->with('users')
    ->select('users.*', DB::raw("CONCAT('http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/', '{$id}/', '{$slug}') AS url"))
    ->orderBy('zlecenia.id', 'desc')
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->where('end',0)
    ->where('kategorie', '>', 0)
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```